# Xcode - Crash: Crashed Thread: 0 Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread

Tags: xcode, xcode5

Everytime I open xcode, and try to do anything with my code, e.g. selecting, clicking, typing, etc., Xcode Crashes. All I get is the following message `Xcode Crash: Crashed Thread: 0 Dispatch Queue: com.apple.main-thread`. With an exception of `EXC_CRASH (SIGILL)`. The strange thing is that this only happens when I open a certain project. After creating a new project, Xcode works fine. So it's like the project is corrupt or something. Since this is the case, do you have some advice on how I can either a) fix the corrupted project or b) transfer everything over to a new project? I'm running Xcode 5.0 by the way. Also this happens only when indexing my project

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. One of my source files had about 200 pluses `+` in one of my methods, for some reason that caused xcode to crash.

Comment: Do you have a cat in your household? :-)